# dramatist remove spacing between speech items

Tags: spacing, lists, tcolorbox, dramatist

I'm typesetting a drama script using the `dramatist` package, which defines the `drama` environment, which is basically a `list` environment, and each speech entry is a list item. Since I need to print the script several times, I want to reduce the space between the speech items.

The `drama` environment declares as follows:

```
\newenvironment{drama}{%
    \if@lnpa
    \PackageWarning{dramatist}{\lnpwarning{a}}
    \fi
    \if@lnps
    \PackageWarning{dramatist}{\lnpwarning{s}}
    \fi
    \list{}{%
        \labelwidth\speakswidth
        \itemindent\speaksindent
        \itemsep\speechskip
        \parsep\Dparsep
        \labelsep\Dlabelsep
        \let\makelabel\speakslabel}
    } {\endlist}
```

The dimensions are also declared in the `dramatist.sty` as follows:

```
\newdimen\speakswidth
\speakswidth\z@
\newdimen\speaksindent
\speaksindent=-\leftmargin
\newdimen\speechskip
\speechskip\itemsep
\newdimen\Dparsep
\Dparsep\z@
\newdimen\Dlabelsep
\Dlabelsep\labelsep
```

It even supports reading a config file:

```
\InputIfFileExists{dramatist.cfg}{\foundfile}{\inputfilewarning}
```

I figured out that the spacing between the items is probably set by the `\speechskip`-dimension, so I tried to create a config file with the following content:

```
\speechskip=0em
\speaksindent=0em
```

The package reads that config file, as stated in the log:

```
Package dramatist Warning: Using Configuration file dramatist.cfg. .
```

But neither the indents nor the skip between the items changes. I don't know why the config file isn't read correctly, since I think that the declarations of the dimensions I done are correct.

A MWE could look like:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\role}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{(\textit{#1})}}
  \begin{CharacterGroup}{Andere alte Leute}
  \GCharacter{Marta \role{Elisa}}{Marta}{marta}
  \end{CharacterGroup}
  \newcommand{\martax}[1]{\item\leavevmode\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\marta,colframe=red]#1\end{tcolorbox}}
  This is the regular document inset.
  \begin{drama}
    \martax{I can talk}
    This is the list inset.
    \martax{I can talk}
    \martax{I can talk}
    \martax{I can talk}
  \end{drama}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output for me:
[image: Example Output MWE]

Any ideas on how to tighten the distance between the items are greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance ;)

**Edit:** Christian Hupfer's answer fixed the spacing between the speech boxes, which I very appreciate ;) What about the spacing to the left? Any ideas are welcome ;)

**Edit 2:** I also tried changing the source of `dramatist.sty` directly in order to fix the bad left indentation, but to no avail: (*of course* for testing purposes only)

```
\newenvironment{drama}{%
    ...
    \list{}{%
        ...
        \itemindent0em
        ...
    } {\endlist}
```

and:

```
\newenvironment{drama}{%
    ...
    \list{}{%
        ...
        \itemindent=0em
        ...
    } {\endlist}
```

**Edit 3:** Using Christian Hupfer's new solution, I was able to reduce the left indentation to a minimum. But there's still a tiny bit of spacing towards the left, and a bit more to right, not much, but it gets visible, when a speechbox is next to some other, unindented content like a colored parbox or some normal text (outside the drama environment). Is there a way to fix this last bit of unwanted spacing?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong position: The spacing is due to `tcolorbox`, which adds a certain amount above and below each box, unless the option `nobeforeafter` is used.

Comment: Sorry, I had no time to look after this all recently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tcolorbox` package puts the `tcolorbox` environments in a paragraph, unless the option `nobeforeafter` is used. A better way to preserve the indents is to apply `before={\hskip\dimexpr\leftmargin-\speechskip}` and an empty `after={}`

The remaining spacing is `\itemsep` and the natural `\interlineskip`. Compare the difference between `\martax` and `\martay`

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\role}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{(\textit{#1})}}
  \begin{CharacterGroup}{Andere alte Leute}
  \GCharacter{Marta \role{Elisa}}{Marta}{marta}
  \end{CharacterGroup}
  \newcommand{\martax}[1]{\item\mbox{}\begin{tcolorbox}[before={\hskip\dimexpr\leftmargin-\speechskip},after={},title=\marta,colframe=red]#1\end{tcolorbox}}
  \newcommand{\martay}[1]{\item\mbox{}\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\marta,colframe=blue]#1\end{tcolorbox}}

  This is the regular document inset.
  \begin{drama}
    \martax{I can talk}
    This is the list inset.
    \martax{I can talk}
    \martax{I can talk}
    \martax{I can talk}
  \end{drama}

  \begin{drama}
    \martay{I can talk}
    This is the list inset.
    \martay{I can talk}
    \martay{I can talk}
    \martay{I can talk}
  \end{drama}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

I changed the text inset and removed the `\mbox{}` commands which lead to the false horizontal spacings.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\newlength{\dramatextinset}
\setlength{\dramatextinset}{\dimexpr-\leftmargin+\labelsep}

\xapptocmd{\drama}{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{\dramatextinset}%
}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure}}

\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\role}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{(\textit{#1})}}
\begin{CharacterGroup}{Andere alte Leute}
  \GCharacter{Marta \role{Elisa}}{Marta}{marta}
\end{CharacterGroup}

\newcommand{\martax}[1]{\item\begin{tcolorbox}[before={},after={},title=\marta,colframe=red]#1\end{tcolorbox}}
\newcommand{\martay}[1]{\item\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\marta,colframe=blue]#1\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}
This is the regular document inset.
\begin{drama}
  \martax{I can talk}

  This is the list inset.
  \martax{I can talk}
  \martax{I can talk}
  \martax{I can talk}
\end{drama}


\begin{drama}
  \martay{I can talk}
  This is the list inset.
  \martay{I can talk}
  \martay{I can talk}
  \martay{I can talk}
\end{drama}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That way I was able to fix the huge spacing between the speech boxes. I didn't think about that the space could be caused by the `tcolorbox`es. But have you any idea how I can remove the huge inset to the left of the speech boxes? Compare the "regular document inset" with the "list inset" statement. Setting `\speaksindent` didn't do the trick, any other ideas? Or is this again caused by the `tcolorbox`?

Comment: @LukeLR: No, I am pretty sure that `dramatist` is the villain here. The `tcolorbox` can be moved nicely left or right. If you say `nobeforeafter` instead of `before={...}` (as I have shown in the code above), the boxes are all aligned left

Comment: Okay. But why doesn't setting `\speaksindent=0em` fix that? Am I missing something?

Comment: @LukeLR: I'll try to figure out

Comment: That's really Nice! I also tried modifying the Source of `dramatist.sty` by directly typing in the definition of the `drama`-environment: `\itemindent0em` or `\itemindent=0em`, which also didn't fix it… :/

Comment: @LukeLR: Please don't edit `.sty` files -- there are other ways to improve such things unless it's effective code.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't have done that for permanent usage, it was for testing purposes only.

Comment: @LukeR: I've got it: `\mbox{}` or `\leavemode` is the culprit. You don't need it -- remove it

Comment: @LukeLR: I've updated with a better variant

Comment: This works very well! I really appreciate your help! But there's still a minimum spacing towards the left border of the document, and an even bigger spacing towards the right.

I know, it's really not much, but it's clearly visible when a speechbox is next to some other, unindented content like some normal text or a `\parbox`. Is there a way we can get rid of that last bit of spacing, too?

Comment: @LukeLR: Hm, actually, there's a rule: One issue per question, not two or more of them. I tried to find the culprits, but you should not insist that `dramatist` is well-designed ;-)

Comment: I thought that this was a connected issue, since I initially wanted to ask about both the spacing, but while writing the question, the spacing between the boxes got into the foreground (unintended), because it seemed more important. Furthermore, I thought opening a new issue would be unwanted, since the scenario is very similiar. But then I'll think about it.

Comment: @LukeLR: I have not much time today, so I'll look tomorrow